# Структуры данных Java. LinkedList

Tags: java

Сегодня хотел изучить списки в Джава и возник такой вопрос. Куда заносятся все элементы в списках? Т.е. для организации полноценной структуры данных, значения должны сохранятся в каком-то массиве или что-то типа этого. А куда сохраняются значения в списках?

Comment: Купите и почитайте книгу Роберта Лафоре "Структуры данных и алгоритмы Java". Очень полезная книга.

Comment: Не очень хороший совет, книга с громадными листингами плохо написанного кода. Лучше какую то общую без привязки к языку книгу по алгоритмам и структурам данным, например, кормена, хотя знающие люди говорят что он тоже не гуд.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Связный список (`LinkedList`) - это динамически изменяемая структура данных, которая строится из набора объектов (узлов `Nodes`), ссылающихся друг на друга (см. рисунок ниже). Каждый узел обычно хранит одну (на следующий узел) или две(на следующий и предыдущий узлы - такой список называется двусвязным) ссылки на соседей и непосредственно значение элемента списка.

Таким образом, значение списка хранится в классах "обертках", которые связаны между собой ссылками.

В самой структуре данных, объекте `LinkedList` хранятся только две ссылки на первый и последний (в двусвязных списках) элемент списка, а доступ к любому элементу списка можно получить переходя по ссылкам узлов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробнее рекомендую посмотреть в книгах, посвященных алгоритмам и структурам данных, например можно начать с книги "Алгоритмы на Java". Авторы: Роберт Седжвик и Кевин Уэйн.

Answer (score 3):

Новосозданный объект типа `LinkedList` имеет в себе два свойства: header и size.

header — псевдоэлемент списка. Его значение всегда равно null, a свойства next и prev всегда указывают на первый и последний элемент списка соответственно. Так как на данный момент список еще пуст, свойства next и prev указывают сами на себя (то есть на элемент header). Размер списка size равен 0.

Иначе говоря, это такие же объекты, которые просто попутно имеют ссылки на предыдущий и следующий объект.

Подробнее можно узнать в статье «[Структуры данных в картинках. LinkedList](https://habrahabr.ru/post/127864/)».

Comment: Совершенно не обязательно, чтобы список имел поле, подсчитывающее количество элементов в списке. И более того нет никакой необходимости, чтобы header был псевдо-элементом, как вы пишите. Вы только вводите в заблуждение автора вопроса.